# speed of parsing json structures

Tags: json, database-design

I want to make a simple database system, amd possibly use JSON as the *main* data format for importing and exporting (including full database backups) . So my question is: how fast is it to parse JSON, even from *big* JSON structures (think gigabytes), in comparison to speed when importing from other systems (like (faster) binary files, or (slower) XML)?

EDIT: to clarify, I am wondering how fast it is to parse JSON (into some internal database format), but not how fast it would be as an internal storage mechanism.
So this JSON data would not be queried etc., but just parsed into another format.

Also, my main intent asking this question is I am wondering if JSON is any easier to parse than XML because of smaller delimiters (']' or '}' instead of '' or ''), and if it is maybe even similar in speed to binary formats because of the quite simple delimiters. 
(For example, maybe json can be parsed something like this: record delimiter = ascii code xx (xx being a brace or bracket) except where preceded by ascii xx (xx being some escape char).)

Comment: By the way, welcome to StackOverflow and hope you stick around :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Benchmarks of JSON, XML, and lots of other things can be found in the [JVM Serializers](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki/) project. The results are too complicated to reproduce here, but the best JSON results (comparing both manual and databound classes) are quite a bit better than the best XML results. That comparison isn't complete, but it's a starting point.

EDIT: as of right now (2012-10-30), there are no published results, because the benchmark is being revised. However, there are some [preliminary results](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki/Staging-Results) available.

Answer (score 5):

It's definitely much, much slower than [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) (for a server) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) (for a client) which are preferrable.

Also, JSON speed depends almost solely on the implementation. For instance, you could `eval()` it, but not only that is very risky, it's also slower than a real parser. At any rate, there are probably much better optimized XML parsers than JSON parsers, just because it's a more used format. (So grab a GB-sized XML and imagine the same results but slower).

Seriously, JSON was never meant for big things. Use a real database if possible.

### Edit: why is JSON much slower than a database?

Many reasons. I'll try to list a few.

- **JSON relies on matching sections such as `{}`s (much like XML's `<>`s)**

This means a parser has to check where's the ending to an object block. There are other of these such as `[]`s and `""`s. In a conventional database there's no "ending tag" or "ending bracket" so it's easier to read.

- **JSON parsers need to read each and every character before being able to understand the whole object structure.**

So before you can even read some of the JSON you have to read the whole file. This means waiting a few minutes at best for the sizes you mentioned, and a database is ready to be queried in less than a second (because the hierarchy is stored at the beginning).

- **In JSON you can't precalculate offsets.**

In a database, size is traded for performance. You can make `VARCHAR(512)` and all strings will be null-padded to occupy 512 bytes. Why? Because that way you can know the 4th value is at offset 2048 for example. You can't do that with JSON hence performance suffers.

- **JSON is optimized for small filesizes.**

...Because it's a web format.
This may look like a pro but it's a con from a performance perspective.

- **JSON is a JavaScript subset.**

So some parsers might allow unnecessary data to be present and considered, such as comments. Chrome's native JSON used to allow comments for example (not anymore).
No database engine uses `eval()` right?

- **JSON is meant to have some error resilience.**

People might put anything into a JSON file, so parsers are defensive and try to read invalid files sometimes. Database aren't supposed to repair a broken file silently.
You might hand-code a JSON but not a database!

- **JSON is a new, unsupported and badly tested format**

There are bugs in some native parsers (like IE8's) and support for most browsers is very preliminary and slower than, say, the fastest XML parser out there. Simply because XML was being used for ages and Steve Ballmer has an XML fetish so companies please him by making almost anything under the sun XML-compatible. While JSON is one of Crockford's successful weekend pasttimes.

- **The best JSON parsers are in browsers**

If you pick one random open-source JSON parser for your favourite language, what chances are that it's the best possible parser under the sun? Well, for XML you do have [awesome parsers like this](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/) But what is there for JSON?

Need more reasons why JSON should be relegated to its intended use case?

Comment: Edited. Slower than XML for sure (the same issues that apply to XML apply to JSON, such as not being able to calculate offsets as easily as in a database).

Comment: @Camilo: There's no reason JSON should be slower than XML. I'd be interested to see some benchmarks showing otherwise.

Comment: @Tom There's no real performance issue with XML, but with XML parsers (like MSXML). All of the DOM issues that XML has apply to JSON if you tried to use JSON as a document format (which you could). The speed of parsing XML can be a little higher just and simply because people have written some few excellent XML parsers that have no JSON counterpart. But I'm not an expert here so maybe you have reasons to believe JSON overcomes some XML-specific limitation?

Comment: By the way a useful benchmark for current status of XML parsers is [here](http://xmlbench.sourceforge.net/results/benchmark200910/index.html).

Comment: I doubt JSON is significantly faster than XML, if at all. They're really very similar formats. JSON is a little more simple and compact, which should help it; as you say, XML parsers have had more time to mature, which should help XML. As a result, without hard data, i don't think you can dismiss JSON on performance grounds.

Comment: @Tom I would dismiss it on the grounds that the parsers aren't mature enough to be reliable (and to provide features like partial parsing) and that since it doesn't adress core issues of XML (like being able to know the offset of some data without having to go through a whole file of tags/brackets to be parsed and without keeping all of that in memory) I doubt it *could* be any faster than XML (besides having less features which makes it simplier, but you could sort-of simulate those features to make JSON more XML-ish and it would then have the same performance woes).

Comment: @Camillo: that benchmark is missing 2 of fastest Java parsers (Woodstox, Aalto), so I don't think it's quite up to date -- not sure why; both were available in 2009. Btw, I  doubt best JSON parsers are in browsers; Java has good ones, c/c++ fast stand-alone ones. At least without seeing some evidence for goodness of whatever browsers use.

Comment: -1 Some arguments are either wrong (e.g. no serious database is padding a VARCHAR on disk: this was true in DBase epoch, not any more), either dubious (opinion based comparison with XML, which is not as good as a database either). Arguing too much is killing the arguments.

Answer (score 4):

If you consider JSON as an intermediate format for data transfer, you might want to consider binary alternatives as well, because they need less disk space and network bandwidth (both compressed and uncompressed), so you may get faster parsing because the input to parse is shorter.

- [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/)
- [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) (binary JSON)
- Google [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)
- Apache & Facebook [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/)
- Python [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) implemented as the `cPickle' module with the highest version
- Python [Marshal](http://docs.python.org/library/marshal.html) (very fast but architecture- and version-dependent)

If you run your own benchmark, make sure to benchmark multiple parsers for the same language, e.g. a JSON parser implemented in pure Python is expected to be much slower than a JSON parser written in C -- but you may find a significant speed difference (up to a factor of 2, but maybe 5) between different implementations in the same programming language as well.

Answer (score 0):

A database is a file system with faster seeking facility. If you can achieve the same with JSON, then things are easy.  You have to make a system to seek things faster from JSON file.